# In HTML, what are the impacts if the main tag isn't nested inside the body tag?

Tags: html

Beginner here.

In HTML, I have tried leaving the main tag outside the body tag as opposed to the proper way with HTML5 to nest the main tag inside the body tag.

It looks the same to me when I opened the HTML file to compare the two.

```
<body></body>
<main></main>

<body><main></main></body>
```

I understand that in HTML5 main tag is supposed to be a part of the body tag but are there any others specific reasons why the main tag is supposed to be nested inside body tag?

What are the impacts if I just leave main outside body? How does it affect the functionality of my code?

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence of the [MDN page on `<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) states

> The `<main>` HTML element represents the dominant content of the `<body>` of a document.

So `<main>` is intended to be used as a part of `<body>`, hence within it.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is completely invalid. The second is correct. Your content must be within the body of the document.

Answer (score 1):

The `<main></main>` tag can only be used once per page, it represents the central topic or core content of the document body and is considered an HTML 5 block element.

The second is valid

```
<body>
<main>

</main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` tag is meant to contain all of the visible content of your web page. In contrast, the `<head>` tag contains meta data about your web page, or to help your web page render correctly (stylesheets, meta data, title, etc...).

As far as I know, there isn't really a good answer for **why** the content goes in the `<body>` tag, other than that's where is is supposed to go, so that's where search engines, browsers, and other bots expect it to be.

More information on the `<body>` tag:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp

The `<main>` tag is meant to contain the main content of your web page and should only appear once. Think of it as a `<div>` tag except it has some additional meaning to help search engines to better understand your web page.

More information on the `<main>` tag:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp

To answer your main question, if your HTML is not structured properly, it will likely still render as you expect it to (browsers are quite forgiving when it comes to visuals). However, search engines and other bots will have a more difficult time understanding your web page properly.

Answer (score 0):

The body tag contains ALL the elements of your HTML code including your header, footer, navigation, etc. The main tag, as introduced in 2021 by Steve Faulkner, is a part of the body tag and cannot be placed elsewhere.
In addition, you cannot have several main tags either. Make note that you cannot place your header nor footer in the main tag. The main tag can only consist of essential elements and information. These elements and information cannot be repeated elsewhere in your code. The main tag helps developers understand where the actual code begins.

The HTML code validator would display an error if

- the main tag is not placed correctly in the body
- or, multiple main tags are used
- or, if the header or footer is part of the main tag
- or, if the main tag is a descendant of the header, nav, article, aside, or footer elements

as the main tag is not meant to be used to section content or otherwise. Therefore, all of the above would be semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

< html >

> This element wraps everything (other than the doctype) in your web page.

< head >

> This element designates the header portion of your document, which includes some information about your web page. The first detail is the title—open your page in a browser, and this title shows up as the caption on the tab.

< body >

> This element holds the meat of your web page, including the actual content you want to be displayed to the world.

So your second one is the correct way to use because of the HTML5 Semantic Tags Structure:

```
<body></body>
<main></main>
```

Also, I found this article explain more about HTML tag: https://www.semrush.com/blog/semantic-html5-guide/